# wpf textbox caret

Tags: wpf, textbox, caret

I'm trying to remove caret blinking from a textbox after the input is done. I've tried focusing another control programmatically and setting IsReadOnlyCaretVisible=false and IsReadOnly on mouseleave event but nothing helps. What should I do? The caret still remains there whatever I do...

Comment: What do you mean by "after the input is done"? Isn't that only guaranteed to be the case when the user changes focus to another control?

Comment: I've entered the text I wanted

Comment: But how does the control know what you want? A user could want to enter anything, even no text at all.

Comment: What determines when input is finished? Are you hitting the Enter key or are you filling the text programmatically?

Comment: I hit the enter key or click out of the textbox

Comment: Are you sure the control has actually lost focus or that focus has not gone back to it for some reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's very strange. The caret should go away when the focus changes, eg when you click out of the textbox. You can't use the old fashioned "HideCaret" WINAPI function, since it's not a standard Windows control - it's WPF.

This question addresses the OPPOSITE of your problem, since your problem isn't supposed to even happen, and the solution was a very simple line of code. Perhaps if you flip the logic around, or find out if your code is already doing this and disable that part - you can get the result you're looking for: [WPF Textbox persist visible caret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859988/wpf-textbox-persist-visible-caret)

Also, if you're using a recent version of WPF, you can probably reassign the brush that the caret uses.

Comment: Ive created a usercontrol with a textbox and I'm adding those controls to Canvas. When I edit the text and then click on canvas or wherever the caret still remains blinking in the textbox... =(