# WPF TextBox show Caret on MouseOver

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, caret

I am looking for a way to show the Caret in a `TextBox` when `IsMouseOver="True"`. The solution using `FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True"` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3058846/7571171) does not seem to work.

Is there a way to show the Caret without having to click inside the `TextBox`?

---

MWE:

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp11.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="FocusManager.IsFocusScope" Value="True" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Width="300" Height="22" Text="Hello World" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

A `TextBox` displaying the Caret after clicking on it. I want the Caret to show already on mouse over.

[image]

Comment: what do you want to do exactly? replace the mousecursor with a carret or...?

Comment: @DenisSchaf when you click in a `TextBox`, a blinking Caret will show. I want to show the blinking Caret when the mouse is over the `TextBox` already, not only after clicking

Comment: uh thats a though one then... i guess youd have to download the original textbox style with the template and remove the trigger that hides it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to set focus, then you need to use `FocusedElement` ([credits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2872306/1997232)):

```
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}"
       TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                 Value="True">
            <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement"
                    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

If you want caret to be initially at the end then consider to initialize all textboxes like this ([credits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2892988/1997232)):

```
<TextBox CaretIndex="{x:Static system:Int32.MaxValue}" ... />
```

where `system` is defined like this:

```
<Window xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" ... />
```

Comment: Nice but it will set carret at index 0.

Comment: @user2250152, this will not change `CaretIndex`, if it was at the end before focus was lost it will stay at the end.